# inner join and group by

Tags: sql-server, group-by, inner-join

I have two tables with identical definition.

```
T1:
Name VARCHAR(50)
Qty  INT

T2:
Name VARCHAR(50)
Qty  INT
```

This is the data each table has:

```
T1:
Name   Qty
a   1
b   2
c   3
d   4

T2:
Name   Qty
a   1
b   3
e   5
f   10
```

I want to have result which can sum the Qty from both the tables based on Name.

Expected resultset:

```
Name    TotalQty
a             2
b             5
c             3
d             4
e             5
f            10
```

If am do Left Join or Right Join, it is not going to return me the Name from either of the tables.

What i am thinking is to create a temp table and add these records and just do a SUM aggregate on Qty column but i think there should be a better way to do this.

This is how my query looks like which does not return the expected resultset:

```
SELECT t1.Name, ISNULL(SUM(t1.Qty + t2.Qty),0) TotalQty
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.Name = T2.Name
GROUP BY t1.Name
```

Can someone please tell me if creating a temp table is OK here or there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Can there be multiple records in t1 or t2 for a name?

Comment: No. There is a unique index on that column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a full outer join:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(t1.Name, t2.Name) AS Name,
    ISNULL(t1.Qty, 0) + ISNULL(t2.Qty, 0) AS TotalQty
FROM t1
FULL JOIN t2 ON t1.Name = T2.Name
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46c5b/2)

Comment: If we have multiple records in t1 or t2 for a name, it will not give the correct results. I think we should have group by on name and instead of just t1.name it should be coalesce(t1.name,t2.name)

Comment: +1; I like that, much cleaner.  I always forget about `FULL JOIN`s for some reason.

Comment: @NitinMidha: Asdfg has stated [in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324086/inner-join-and-group-by/12324126#comment16540252_12324086) that there cannot be multiple records in t1 or t2 for a name because there is a unique index.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `UNION ALL` to select both tables as one, since they have the same definition.  From there, you can nest them as a derived table, and then `SUM` on that:

```
SELECT [Name], SUM(Qty) AS TotalQty
FROM (
    SELECT [Name], Qty
    FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Name], Qty
    FROM t2
) YourDerivedTable
GROUP BY [Name]
```

Comment: @Asdfg - yes it should!  Edited